# How to create a query in Data Method to select from OLAP cube in moxl reports?

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx, axapta

I can without any problems run a sql query in DataMethods in Business Intelligence when I use DynamicsReports.

Question: How to use the same way for MDX query?

I want to run a MDX query in DataMethod because I need to work with the results - to use Linq to Datatable.

Is any way to do that, or to run a DataSet in DataMethod?

Comment: Please make your questions more clear! What is your objective? What is a MDX query? Do you mean a direct SQL against the AX database?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want data access methods similar to SQL for MDX as well.
You can created linked server for SSAS and use openquery to exec MDX.

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(linked_server_olap, mdx_query)
```

You can execute this as sql statement / store procedure

Other alternative would be using [ADOMD.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123483%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)